# Probability distribution of $W_{q}$ in an $M/M/2$ queuing system

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

For an $M/M/1$ queuing system, a probability distribution of the waiting time in the queue can be written as 
$$\mathbb{P}(W_{q}> t)= \rho e^{-\mu t(1-\rho)}$$
where $t$ is some time and $\rho$, as usual, is equal to $\frac{\lambda }{\mu }$.

For an $M/M/2$ queuing system, I know that 
$$W_{q} = \frac{\rho ^{2}}{\mu (1-\rho ^{2})}.$$
Does anyone know how to derive an expression for the probability distribution of $W_{q}$ for an $M/M/2$ system?  I know it exists, because I have seen it before, but I can't seem to derive or remember it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first use of $W_q$ treats it as a random variable, while your second use of $W_q$ treats it as an expectation. For consistency, it is better to use $\overline{W}_q$ for the second expression.

Comment: Assuming $W_q$ is the random delay in the _queue_ (not including service time) then $W_q=0$ if we arrive and see at least one server is empty. If we arrive and see both servers active and $n$ in the queue, then $W_q$ is the sum of $n+1$ iid exponential random variables with rate $2\mu$.  So you can use PASTA, conditioning, and the steady state probabilities for queue occupancy.